# How to put user defined datatype into a Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to define my own data type and put it in a Dictionary as a value. VBA complains that it does not accept my data type. Any ideas about how to get this working?

```
Option Explicit

Public Type Translation
    german As String
    french As String
    italian As String
End Type

Private resource As Object

Public Sub addTranslation(key As String, g As String, f As String, i As String)
    Dim trx As Translation
    trx.german = g
    trx.french = f
    trx.italian = i

    resource.add key, trx  '<== here VBA is complaining
End Sub

Public Sub initResource()
    If resource Is Nothing Then Set resource = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
End Sub
```

This is the error messge:

> Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound modules.

Comment: Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound modules.

Comment: If you change the line to "resource.Add key, trx.french" then it will compile, but I cant' tell what your goal is.  Does "bla" = "add"?

Comment: Thanks! Improved the question.

Comment: No, resource.Add key, trx.french would not help, the intention is to have all languages stored by one key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some more digging i found this answer:

If you want to put a user defined data type into a Dictionary of Collection, you have to define it as class. You can do so by adding a new class module and just adding this code:

```
Public german As String
Public french As String
Public italian As String
```

Since I named the class module *trans*, my resulting code looks like this:

```
Private resource As Object

Public Sub addTranslation(k As String, g As String, f As String, i As String)
    Dim trx As trans
    Set trx = New trans
    trx.german = g
    trx.french = f
    trx.italian = i

    resource.Add k, trx
End Sub

Public Sub initTranslations()
    If resource Is Nothing Then Set resource = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
End Sub
```

Now I can dynamically add translations.

Comment: Thanks. This is so dumb, and applies to returning arrays of a user defined type/class too...

Comment: I step away from VBA, I swear it off forever.  I return, dabbling.  I forget myself and wade back in.... until disappointment washes over me anew... Carrying with it is the shame of being fooled a second time.  Concise Q&A.