# VBA: Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to a late-bound functions

Tags: vba, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-sl

**Compile Error:**

> Compile Error: Only user-defined types defined in public object
>   modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to a late-bound
>   functions.

I'm new to VBA and I was tasked with debugging some code for a custom screen in Dynamics SL. The first thing I did was to see if it compiled and I got the above message.

When I read the built-in help reference I found the following for the above error:

> You attempted to use a public user defined type as a parameter or
>   return type for a public procedure of a class module, or as a field of
>   a public user defined type. Only public user defined types that are
>   defined in a public object module can be used in this manner.

I also went through these similar questions:

- [How to put user defined datatype into a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178177/how-to-put-user-defined-datatype-into-a-dictionary)
- [Only user-defined type defined in public object modules can be coerced when trying to call an external VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046552/only-user-defined-type-defined-in-public-object-modules-can-be-coerced-when-tryi)

They have the same error but I don't see a collection object that the above two questions focused on.

If you may have any idea what may be causing this error please don't hesitate to suggest it.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub cpjt_entity_Chk(ChkStrg As String, retval As Integer)
Dim ldDate As Sdate
Dim xStrDailyPost As Sdate

ldDate.val = GetObjectValue("cpe_date")
'xStrDailyPost = DateToStr(ldDate)
'Call MsgBox("Daily Post Date: " & xStrDailyPost, vbOKOnly, "TEST")
serr1 = SetObjectValue("cld_id08", xStrDailyPost) <- Error highlights "xStrDailyPost"

End Sub
```

Definition for SetObjectValue:

```
Declare Function SetObjectValue Lib "swimapi.dll" Alias "VBA_SetObjectValue" (ByVal ctlname$, newval As Variant) As Integer
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error is not caused by collections, but may happen while using them because they accept a `Variant` like the error description says. What is `SetObjectValue`, how is its second parameter declared, and where is `Sdate` declared?

Comment: Sdate appears to be a user defined type.  where is Sdate declared?

Comment: @GSerg, That's a good question. I'm currently looking in a screen object and it's not declared in here. I also looked in the modules related to this screen and no mention of this function in there either. I guess something got lost or deleted. Would it normally be in this screen or a Module?

Comment: Right click `Sdate` or `SetObjectValue` and select `Definition`.

Comment: @JonathanPorter Sounds like you are missing the class module for Sdate

Comment: @GSerg, Thank you. I found the following for SetObjectValue: Declare Function SetObjectValue Lib "swimapi.dll" Alias "VBA_SetObjectValue" (ByVal ctlname$, newval As Variant) As Integer

Comment: @Sorceri, when I right click on Sdate and click on definition as GSerg suggested I see the error: "Identifier under cursor is not recognized" Does this confirm/contradict your belief that this is related to a missing class module?

Comment: @JonathanPorter yes, there is no class Sdate.  You will need to recreate it or use a different type.

Comment: So you have an external function that accepts a `Variant`, and you are trying to pass a (presumably) used defined type to it. You cannot do that like the error description says. As for not found definition for `Sdate`, it may or may not mean you are missing a reference (`Definition` is not always perfect). Press F2 and search for `Sdate` there to be sure. It might be that you are missing a reference to a library that contains definition for `Sdate`, then you will be able to run that code.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I'll update my question if I can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working with code that was originally written with the Dynamics SL (actually it was Solomon IV at the time) Basic Script Language (BSL) macro language instead of VBA.

Regardless... the fix is, pass results of the "val" method of your xStrDailyPost instance of SDate.  SO the code should look like:

```
serr1 = SetObjectValue("cld_id08", xStrDailyPost.val)
```

I've not actually tested this but I'm pretty sure this will address your issue.

If you want a little more background, "Sdate"  is really just a very thin wrapper of an integer (actually I think it's a short, but I've never found I really needed to know for sure).  the "Val" method returns the underlying integer in the SDate variable.